# Run a script during shutdown/termination of an aws instance

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, debian

I need to execute a script during shutdown/termination of an AWS instance(debian).

I added my script to the `/etc/init.d/myscript` and a symlink to `/etc/rc0.d/K01myscript` however I noticed that when I terminate the instance I don't see that my script is executed.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I would not expect Amazon to terminate an instance gracefully.  During an normal O/S shutdown, sure you can run a kill script.  But not a terminate.  If you're interested in being notified that it was terminated then take look at attaching [EC2 CloudWatch events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html#ec2_event_type) to the instance.  According to the docs you can get:

> This example of an EC2 Instance State-change Notification event shows
>   the instance in the pending state. The other possible values for state
>   include running, shutting-down, stopped, stopping, and terminated.

with a JSON package like:

```
{
   "id":"7bf73129-1428-4cd3-a780-95db273d1602",
   "detail-type":"EC2 Instance State-change Notification",
   "source":"aws.ec2",
   "account":"123456789012",
   "time":"2015-11-11T21:29:54Z",
   "region":"us-east-1",
   "resources":[
      "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:instance/i-abcd1111"
   ],
   "detail":{
      "instance-id":"i-abcd1111",
      "state":"pending"
   }
}
```

If you really need to handle this then you'll have to shutdown the O/S first which will run your script and then terminate the stopped instance.